# Identity Toolkit does not work - Error code: Bad response from IDP

Tags: javascript, html, google-identity-toolkit

The problem that I am currently unable to solve is `bad response from IDP` and the cause is supposed to be the lack of `mode=select` but I'm unaware now about the page where the `mode=select` must be implemented

As a matter of fact I have added the code into two separated pages, the first one is index.php which does the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
apiKey: 'AIzaSyAaMAfu7S2AITODrGJzVkIYBXlZR3FYhuQ',
signInSuccessUrl: 'http://www.lascuolacheverra.org/signin?mode=select', // i tried to add the `mode=select here`
signInOptions: ["google", "password"],
idps: ["Google", "AOL", "Microsoft", "Yahoo", "Facebook"],
oobActionUrl: '/',
siteName: 'La scuola che verrà A.P.S.',
    
    // Optional - function called after sign in completes and before
    // redirecting to signInSuccessUrl. Return false to disable
    // redirect.
    // callbacks: {
    //  signInSuccess: function(tokenString, accountInfo,
    //    opt_signInSuccessUrl) {
    //      return true;
    //    }
    // },
    
    // Optional - key for query parameter that overrides
    // signInSuccessUrl value (default: 'signInSuccessUrl')
    // queryParameterForSignInSuccessUrl: 'url'
    
    // Optional - URL of site ToS (linked and req. consent for signup)
     tosUrl: 'http://www.lascuolacheverra.org/privacypolicy.html',
    
    // Optional - URL of callback page (default: current url)
    // callbackUrl: 'http://example.com/callback',
    
    // Optional - Cookie name (default: gtoken)
    //            NOTE: Also needs to be added to config of the ‘page with
    //                  sign in button’. See above
    // cookieName: ‘example_cookie’,
    
    // Optional - UI configuration for accountchooser.com
    acUiConfig: {
     title: 'Sign in to lascuolacheverra.org',
     favicon: 'http://www.lascuolacheverra.org/favicon.ico',
     branding: 'http://www.lascuolacheverra.org/images/lascuolacheverra.jpg'
     },
    
    
    // Optional - Function to send ajax POST requests to your Recover URL
    //            Intended for CSRF protection, see Advanced Topics
    //      url - URL to send the POST request to
    //     data - Raw data to include as the body of the request
    //completed - Function to call with the object that you parse from
    //            the JSON response text. {} if no response
    /*ajaxSender: function(url, data, completed) {
     },
     */
};
// The HTTP POST body should be escaped by the server to prevent XSS
window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
                                    '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
                                    config,
                                    '{{ POST_BODY }}');
</script>

<!-- End modification -->
```

---

The second part of the code is in another index.php and does the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Copy and paste here the "Sign-in button javascript" you downloaded from Developer Console as gitkit-signin-button.html -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<link type=text/css rel=stylesheet href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />
<script type=text/javascript>
window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
                                           '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
                                           {
                                           widgetUrl: "/widget",
                                           signOutUrl: "/",
                                           }
                                           );
</script>

<!-- End configuration -->

</head>
<body>

<!-- Include the sign in button widget with the matching 'navbar' id -->
<div id="navbar"></div>
<!-- End identity toolkit widget -->

<p>
{{ CONTENT }}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how I have to proceed in order to correctly use `mode=select` since as of today Identity Toolkit is available to my homepage but I can't use it to the fullest because of this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> signInSuccessUrl:
>   'http://www.lascuolacheverra.org/signin?mode=select', // i tried to
>   add the `mode=select here`

This should not point to the `/signin` page. Maybe point it to `/` or `/signed-in`.

Also, remove

> // signInOptions: ["google", "password"], // <-- this apparently masks out the idps
>
> idps: ["Google", "AOL", "Microsoft", "Yahoo", "Facebook"],

I did some testing with this, and if I add signInOptions, then idps is ignored and you end up only being able to sign in with google and password.

Apparently only using signInOptions [is the way to do it](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend). I've read idps instead of signInOptions in other examples, and I'm using idps with success.

**Update** I misread the code a bit. I thought `\signin` was the page showing the widget, which the tutorials place under `\widget`. My mistake because in my project I'm replacing `\widget` with `\secure-sign-in`. So, if your `\signin` page is not the `\widget` page then your code was already OK. And in any case you should remove the `?mode=select` because this is only used for the `\widget` and is added automatically by the `window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton` function.

Comment: I'll let you know asa i try it

Comment: I have removed the signInOptions but still does not work, please reply to this comment as soon as you can my friend

Comment: In the meantime I replaced `idps` with `signInOptions`, both work. Is your first index.html reachable as `/widget` and the second as `/`? Also, in the second index.html you're citing the entire file content, in the first one only the javascript code. I hope your first one doesn't contain only that code. Is that piece of javascript all that this page at `/widget` is containing?

Comment: may we move this discussion to chat?

Comment: we must keep commenting here till appears move discussion to chat to avoid extended comments

Comment: i am sure that i'm doing something wrong but really i am unable to find the bug

Comment: I also did another mistake, I didn't differentiate between `/` and `/signin`. Why are you making this distinction. I mention this because your signOut points to `/` instead of `/signin`. This is not a technical problem. What does the {{ POST_BODY }} contain? Maybe keep it empty once to test if this is the source of the problem?

Comment: I have removed mode select from index.php but still it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84997/discussion-between-riccardo990-and-daniel-f).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two pages. Let's say url1 and url2.

url1 where you include your sign in button by running:

window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton()

Set widgetUrl to url2

In url2 where you render the widget by running:

window.google.identitytoolkit.start()

Set the signInSuccessUrl to url1

Do not add ?mode=select to widget url. On sign in button click, it will automatically append it to that url and redirect there.

Comment: i wan to to clarify this I have used two different pages: index.php under the templates folder which is the main page that handles the general functioning of the website, plus I have created another page always called index.php under the gitkit directory that's why I am not able to understand what is wrong plus Google emailed me stating how important is the use of mode=select and when I tried to ask the proper use and how to do it I was replied ask your question on stack so please solve me this strange problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was just encountering the same error "Error code: Bad response from IDP."

As stated in the comments above there are two possibilites:

1. creation of a page with a SignIn-Button only and another one to which the previous one redirects on button click
2. appending `"?mode=select"` to the url as a query parameter
3. Redirect in your routes, for example on

   ```
   app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
     res.redirect("/login?mode=select");        
   }
   ```

The [gitkit.js](http://www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js) [extracts it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYfD2.png) from the browsers `window.location.href`.